# Python: is it possible to return a variable amount of variables as requested?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to return either one or two variables for a function in python(3.x). Ideally, that would depend on amount of returned variables requested by user on function call. For example, the `max()` function returns by default the max value and can return the argmax. In python, that would look something like:

```
maximum = max(array)
maximum, index = max(array)
```

Im currently solving this with an extra argument return_arg:

```
import numpy as np

def my_max(array, return_arg=False):
   maximum = np.max(array)

   if return_arg:
      index = np.argmax(array)
      return maximum, index
   else:
      return maximum
```

This way, the first block of code would look like this:

```
maximum = my_max(array)
maximum, index = my_max(array, return_arg=True)
```

Is there a way to avoid the extra argument? Maybe testing for how many vaules the user is expecting? I know you can return a tuple and unpack it when calling it (that's what I'm doing).

Asume the actual function I'm doing this in is one where this behaviour makes sense.

Comment: If you  make the function return a list or single object, then check the length rather than immediately unpacking, then you can ignore the extra parameter... Or always return the value, and externally, conditionally get it

Comment: I agree with @cricket_007 wouldn't it just be as easy as checking the length of the array parameter with `len(array)`?

Comment: This isn't Matlab. There's no `nargout` here.

Comment: I didn't quite understand @cricket_007 's comment. But the fact that there is no notion of the caller inside the excecution of a function means, as you said, I won't be able to do it.

Comment: My comment was saying `return [max, None]` or always `[max, index]`, then get position `[1]` externally to the function based on your condition that you would have otherwise added as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead return an instance of a subclass of `int` (or `float`, depending on the data type you want to process) that has an additional `index` attribute and would return an iterator of two items when used in a sequence context:

```
class int_with_index(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, index):
        return super(int_with_index, cls).__new__(cls, value)
    def __init__(self, value, index):
        super().__init__()
        self.index = index
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self, self.index))

def my_max(array, return_arg=False):
   maximum = np.max(array)
   index = np.argmax(array)
   return int_with_index(maximum, index)
```

so that:

```
maximum = my_max(array)
maximum, index = my_max(array)
```

would both work as intended.

Comment: This is exactly what I wnted. After reding about `super()` and the `__new__` method I think I follow what this does: upon instantiation, it calls the overriten overwritten `__new__` which passes `value` to the base class `__new__` (which for ome reason takes in a `value` parameter). Then, it initiates the base class and add the atribute index to my class. I don't get why `iter(self, ...)` returns the value and not the instance and why it doesn't rise an error when trying to unpack using `iter()` in he return statement. I'd love to fully understand this answer...

Comment: Also, I tried to modify it to suit my needs, where I actually need to return two numpy arrays of same size, not two numbers. I didn't post the question as such couse I didn't know the anser would be different. I tried rewriting the code using the `np.ndarray`, but it seems I need to understand how its `__new__` method works. I guess it has something to do with the reason why you pass `value` to the `__new__` of `int`. I you could give me a hint on that, I'd be very glad.

Comment: Clarification question: why do `__new__`  and `__init__` need `index` and ´value´, respectively, when the explicitly call only one of them?

Comment: Ah, if you want to use a data type that already has `__iter__` defined then my method won't work, which is the case for `np.ndarray`, because your subclass would be overriding `np.ndarray`'s own `__iter__` so you won't be able to iterate over its items anymore. The signatures of `__new__` and `__init__` have to match each other because their arguments both come from the same constructor call (`int_with_index(maximum, index)` in my example), so I have to include both parameters even though I only use one of them in each method.

Comment: OK, I get it now. I also get why my `__iter__` methd wsn't behaving as as wanted. My last try was to just create a `dummy` class with two atributes array1 and array2, and have `__iter__` iterate over a tuple of those arrays. Of course when I call my function with one output I get an instance of `dummy`, and when I call it with two outputs, when it tries to unpack it call `__iter__` which effectively unpacks the result. Still, not the intended behaviour. The secret to your answer working is that `self` returns the value of the integer, not the instance.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of doing this. `my_max(array)` will be called and return before assigning a value to `maximum`. If more than one value is returned by the function then it will try unpacking the values and assigning them accordingly.
Most people tackle this problem by doing this:

```
maximum, _ = my_max(array)
maximum, index = my_max(array)
```

or

```
maximum = my_max(array)[0]
maximum, index = my_max(array)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I usually do, but given the useage I'll give to my function, I'll stick to my solution. Also, I think you might want to delete the `return_arg` from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**, in Python a function has no context of the caller and can't know how many values the caller expects in return.

Instead in Python you would rather have different functions, a flag in the function signature (like you did) or you would return an object with multiple fields of which the consumer can take whatever it needs.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. This is no matlab, as someone said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution that works for any data type such as `np.ndarray`, you can use a decorator that uses `ast.NodeTransformer` to modify any assignment statement that assigns a call to a given target function name (e.g. `my_max`) to a single variable name, to the same statement but assigns to a tuple of the same variable name plus a `_` variable (which by convention stores a discarded value), so that a statement such as `maximum = my_max(array)` is automatically transformed into `maximum, _ = my_max(array)`:

```
import ast
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent

class ForceUnpack(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, target_name):
        self.target = ast.dump(ast.parse(target_name, mode='eval').body)
    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, ast.Call) and ast.dump(node.value.func) == self.target and isinstance(node.targets[0], ast.Name):
            node.targets[0] = ast.Tuple(elts=[node.targets[0], ast.Name(id='_', ctx=ast.Store())], ctx=ast.Store())
            return node
    # remove force_unpack from the decorator list to avoid re-decorating during exec
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        node.decorator_list = [
            decorator for decorator in node.decorator_list
            if not isinstance(decorator, ast.Call) or decorator.func.id != "force_unpack"
        ]
        self.generic_visit(node)
        return node

def force_unpack(target_name):
    def decorator(func):
        tree = ForceUnpack(target_name).visit(ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func))))
        ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
        scope = {}
        exec(compile(tree, inspect.getfile(func), "exec"), func.__globals__, scope)
        return scope[func.__name__]
    return decorator
```

so that you can define your `my_max` function to always return a tuple:

```
def my_max(array, return_arg=False):
   maximum = np.max(array)
   index = np.argmax(array)
   return maximum, index
```

while applying the `force_unpack` decorator to any function that calls `my_max` so that the assignment statements within can unpack the returning values of `my_max` even if they're assigned to a single variable:

```
@force_unpack('my_max')
def foo():
    maximum = my_max(array)
    maximum, index = my_max(array)
```